# guide for iphone developers on developing for android?

Tags: android, iphone, sdk

I know there are guides for android developers to learn iphone programming, and they try and compare and contrast differences between the two platforms to help developers learn, but is there a guide for the opposite? A guide/introduction to android development for developers coming from an iphone dev background?

Comment: could you post the link , i know android and i need the guide to learn iphone development

Answer (score 1):

I dont think there is a guide that compare iphone and android developement (May be I am wrong). From my experience (I started on iphone, now working on both) you should be aware of these things

iphone OS targets some standard devices which has fixed resolution and screen size. So we can align widgets in places by giving absolute pixel values. But in the case of android, we have to target different kind of devices, by different vendors, with different screen size and resolution. So to design and program UI you will need to learn about the concept called layouts.

For iphone we know there is only one soft keyboard. Different android devices comes up with hard and soft keyboards. And let me tell you handling android soft keyboard event can be most frustrating(From my experience).

memory management in ios is tough to learn, there is no garbage collector there, but easy if you understood the concepts. There is garbage collector in android(java) so we dont have to think about memory.

For learning android some links I have bookmarked.(not comparisons between iphone and android)

http://www.devx.com/wireless/Article/39101

http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/opensource/tutorials/os-eclipse-androidwidget/index.html?ca=dgr-eclipse-1

http://mobiforge.com/designing/story/understanding-user-interface-android-part-1-layouts

http://saigeethamn.blogspot.com/2010/05/table-of-contents.html

Answer (score 1):

If you want to get something up and running quickly to get a feel of things, I found this short series of articles, [Android for iOS developers](http://clayallsopp.posterous.com/building-an-android-app-from-scratch-or-this) to be pretty good. There are a couple of errors here and there and you'll have to get past the author's style but I had a quick and dirty port of a similar iOS app up and running in a few hours.

As an aside, the Android SDK is a bit of a faff to get running on Mac OS X. I skipped it and installed on a Windows PC but you'll want a good guide tailored for that as well. There are a lot of steps compared to "install xcode".